# Dynamically changing the data displayed using ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have a problem with manipulating data from ajax and jQuery.

I am using jQuery to display html code and insert it into the div element "#kontener"

```
$.ajax({
    url: "qa.php",
    type: "POST",
    datatype: "html",
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=iso-8859-2",
    data: {
        indeks: tekst, q: question},
    success: function (result) {
        jQuery("#kontener").html(result);
    },
});
```

Here is sample html

```
<table id="q">
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="1">q1</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="2">q2</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="3">q3</td></tr>
    <tr><td><input type="radio" name="answer" value="4">q4</td></tr>
</table>
```

Question - can I use jQuery to select the radio button after clicking on the tr element?

Unfortunately this doesn't work :(

```
$("tr").click(function () {
   $(this).find('input:radio').attr('checked', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
$(this).find('input:radio').prop('checked', true);
```

I recommend giving each radio a unique ID

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get this to work:

```
$("#q tr").click(function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

This worked, as well:

```
$("#q").on( "click", "tr", function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! I slightly modified the code and it works :) Here's the final version:

`$("#kontener").on( "click", "tr", function() {
    $(this).find("input[type=radio]").prop("checked", true);
});`

Answer (score 0):

Use `setAttribute` function.

```
$("tr").click(function () {
    $(this).find('input:radio')[0].setAttribute('checked', true)
});
```